# Using tslearn for DTW K-means clustering with Sakoe-Chiba radius

Tags: k-means, dtw, windows-clustering

I am using tslearn for dynamic time warping and I want to apply Sakoe-Chiba radius for the pairwise calculation. I am not sure if the below code is computed based on pairwise calculation for the time series dataset shape (16652, 24, 1).

`n_clusters=3 sakoe_chiba_radius = 1 dba_km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, metric='dtw', metric_params={"sakoe_chiba_radius": sakoe_chiba_radius}) y_pred = dba_km.fit_predict(time_series_dataset)`

If I am wrong, can you please suggest a correct way to code?